# How do I properly calculate this time complexity

Tags: time-complexity, big-o, complexity-theory

I'm examining this code as preparation for my test and I'm having some problems figuring out what is the correct time complexity:

```
a = 1;
while (a < n) {
 b = 1;
 while (b < a^2)
  b++;
a = a*2;
}
```

The values for `a` are as follows : `1, 2, 4, 8, ... , 2^(logn) = n`

Therefore we have `logn` iterations for the outer loop.
In every nested loop, there are `a^2` iterations, so basically what I've come up with is:

```
T(n) = 1 + 4 + 16 + 64 + ... + (2^logn)^2
```

I'm having problems finding the general term of this series and therefore getting to a final result.
(maybe due to being completely off in my calculations though)

Would appreciate any help, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your calculations are alright, you are correct with your analysis of the inner while-loop. We can demonstrate this with a small table:

[image]

This is basically the sum of a geometric progression with:
`a1 = 1, q = 4, #n = lg n + 1`

Where `#n` is the number of elements.
We have: `Sn = 1 * (4^(lgn +1) - 1)/(4-3) = (4*n^2 - 1)/3`

Thus we can say your code running complexity is `Θ(n^2)`

Mathematical explanation in LaTeX:

[image]